# how to install the pdfpages package?

Tags: installing, pdfpages

I need a step-by-step (very simple like myself) instructions on how to install the `pdfpages` package. It's taken me time to figure out I didn't have the package. Now I've found and downloaded it... but I don't know how to install it...

I've attempted to open up the `pdfpages.ins` within the `Texstudio` and click on the green arrow to execute and I get this error message:

```
Could not start Build & View: PdfLatex: C:\... location" -synctex=1 - interaction=nonstopmode"pdfpages".txt.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that error means that pdftex could not start it is not an error about any tex package. have you installed tex (miktex or texlive) ? not just an editor such as texstudio?

Comment: you should never have to install pdfpages "by hand" by processing the `.ins` file, just install the package via the texlive or miktex package system, but you need to install tex first.

Comment: Yes, I've installed Texstudio and have been successful writing the needed document; however, now I wish to add a pdf document to the appendix and I'm receiving this error... I was able to add a jpeg quite easily by using the \usepackage{graphic} -- but all the trouble started when I tried to execute \usepackage{pdfpages}…

Comment: as I say installing just texstudio is the most common cause for that error. Are you using miktex or texlive if you said which tex system you were using someone could tell you how to update it to include pdfpages. you should not need to process the `.ins` file at all, but i note that your error message shows you were trying `pdfpages.txt` not `.ins`

Comment: try any of the answers to these https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=texstudio+could+not+start

Comment: Thank you thank you!! -- I've just downloaded and installed miktex. Now what are the next steps?

Comment: Open  `MiKTeX console` 'administrator mode), select `packages` to see the list of packages, right-click on `pdfpages` and  click on `install package`.

Comment: what did you mean by  I've installed Texstudio and have been successful writing the needed document;" in your earlier comment? If you had not installed tex then no latex document could have worked (I do not have texstudio or miktex so I leave others to fill in the details there)

Comment: To help you further we would need confirmation your TeX engines are working and up to date. In a Windows console it is easy to run `Where /r \ pdfLaTeX` and note the result then run `Where $path:pdflatex` and check the result is one line EXACTLY the same as one from the first Where if the two do not have an agreement then tex is not going to be in agreement with anything else. There may be more than one answer to the first `where` BUT NO MORE OR LESS than 1 answer to the `where $path:pdflatex` unless you know exactly how to control that. MiKTeX-console should be working for you well now ?

Comment: Bernard - Thank you very much for your reply. Success!!